# Return value for mySql UPDATE

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm working on a springboot app and have this update function in my Mapper class that updates the field `groupId` if `groupId` exists in the DB.

```java
@Update("UPDATE user SET groupId = " +
            "IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM allGroup WHERE groupId = #{groupId}) is true, #{groupId}, groupId) " +
            "WHERE email = #{email}")
int updateUserGroup(@Param("groupId") Integer groupId, @Param("email") String email);
```

This function returns 1 regardless of whether `groupId` was really updated. Is there a way to tell if that field was changed? Having the function return 0 or something when no changes were made for example. Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain that `updateUserGroup()` in fact returns 1 even for queries with a non matching `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yep, this is how I called it:`int result = groupMapper.updateUserGroup(groupId, email);`.  `result` is only 0 when `email` isn't in the database, otherwise it's always 1.

Comment: ...and this is the expected behavior.  Even if the update _doesn't_ change the value, it still counts as an update having taken place.

Comment: This is framework issue, it seems - it returns the value for matched rows amount and not for affected rows amount. You need in separate query for to retrieve the amount of the rows updated practically.